# Multiple input fields painted via loop not updating new values on insertion in react and redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am working in React with Redux.Things looked very free flowing untill I came across one problem.May be I am not implementing this particular part the right way.However I need your help in this.

So I have a react component and on componentWillMount() I get data from an API call

I have my actions and action creators in place such that it dispatches a getSupplier action,I store them in redux state as supplierList which is an array of objects like 
[{name:'Bob',score:10,id:1},{name:'John',score:10,id:2}];

Now My UI comprises of a table with name and score as table data.Score will be an input field which will initially have score values which came from the getSupplier service.

I have looped and returned the jsx inside my component as follow

```
   render(){
       var data = this.props.supplierList;
       if(data.length){
            return (
               <div className='fx-container'>
                   {
                     data.map((v,i)=>{
                         (<div class='fx-table-row' key={v.id}>
                            <div class='fx-supp-name'>{v.name}</div>
                            <input 
                            type='text'
                            className='fx-input' 
                            value={v.score}
onChange={(e)=>{this.handleInputChange(e.target.value)}}
                            onBlur={(e)=>    {this.props.actions.updateScore(v.id,e.target.value)}}
                          </div>);
                      });
                   }
               <div>
            );
        }
      else{
        return null;
      }

    }
```

So I am painting my intial values and on inserting of new value and on blur I need to update the new value by dispatching an action which is written in action.js file
The probblem I am facing is that I am not able to insert any value into the input.I am not able to hit backspace and insert new values.

Kindly help as I am new to react and redux.
PS: Above code is a dummy code just to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Can you show code of updateScore() function.

Comment: Hi Vladimir.Updatescore function code is working fine.It does get triggered when I blur out of the input however my concern is that I am not been able to insert new input values inside the input.The input simply doesnt update its value attribute

Comment: What I am saying is you should call this.props.actions.updateScore() function on onChange() event so that props.supplierList change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might not want to call an API in componentWillMount. See this post: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

The reason you're not able to modify your input is that this is a controlled field and you're not calling an onChange event. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Also, you should provide a key to your mapped items. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I had put keys and onChange method in my original code.Sorry just missed while typing over here.Just updated.However my next question is what should I be doing inside onChange? Do I need to dispatch an action to change my redux state and hold new values on input change and re-render everything again ? I made it work by doing so,but I am not sure  whether I am following the right approach

Comment: Yes. Dispatch an action to update score. Alternatively you could look into something like https://redux-form.com/

Comment: Thanks @ovation22.So basically I will be re-rendering everything on typing each character inside the input because my onChange will dipatch an action and that will inturn trigger re-rendering with new values. Is'nt this a costly thing to do?Just curious to know

Comment: Depending on how you're storing state, what you're doing in render, etc., it could be less performant. Here's a good read on redux performance: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs.I will surely have a read on redux performance :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `value={v.score}`

The value of Input field is controlled by `v.score` and it is from `props`

So in the `this.props.actions.updateScore()` function you should change the `score` so that the `props` change.

The value of Input field will never change unless the `props` are changed

Also you should use `onChange()` instead of `onBlur()`

Comment: Thanks for replying  Vladimir.So basically I will be re-rendering everything on typing each character inside the input because my onChange will dipatch an action and that will inturn trigger re-render with new values.Wont this hamper the performance ? Is there any alternative way ?

Comment: Be honestly there is no alternative as React.js is developed that way.

Comment: Is that so.Okay.Anyways thanks a lot for your inputs :)